# d3-force prevent single nodes from moving

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am using d3-force simulation on a network with linked as well as single nodes.

The problem is:
The force pushes everything far off.

What I would want is, the force to only act on nodes which are linked and if they are pushed towards each other or 2 linked components are overlapping.

```
var simulation = d3Force.forceSimulation()
        .alphaDecay(0)
        .force("link", d3Force.forceLink()
                              .distance(60)
                              .strength(0.5)
                              .id(function(d) { return d.index; }))
.force("charge", d3Force.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
               .restart();
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `forceX` and `forceY` to your force simulation can fix the problem. Here is an example:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(0.1))
    .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0.1));
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to be using a centring force to pull your "unlinked" nodes in `d3.forceCenter([x, y])`. But this would also draw in your linked nodes, so maybe adjust the link strength (-ve if necessary) to push linked ones back apart.

Making the force work differently on linked/unlinked nodes is way beyond me.